# How to do a comparison value

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

I built this automated Aquaponics system using (Drum role) a RaspPi :) and used that opportunity to learn how to code with Python. This was an amazing project as my 1st one but now I have reached my coding limit. I have multiple Water sensors HC-SR04 in my growbed and when I'm pumping water into it the sensor measures the distance. If it reaches a preset distance then the pump is instructed to stop.

This is working great but my redundancy brain is always in alarm. What happens if the sensor fails? then the pump is still pumping and I'm left with a call to the insurance because of water damage (this is an indoor project 40 Gal tank).

How would I code this so that the pump would stop if one of the following values is reached 1st? Either water level is 4cm from the sensor or 2 min worth of pumping?

```
def Pumping_to_Growbed():
print ('')
print ('Pumping water to growbed')
time.sleep(1)
distance = Growbed_Sensor1_Measurement()
print ('Distance ', distance ,'cm')
while distance > 4:
   GPIO.output(RELAY_1, False)
   print ('distance ', distance ,'cm')
   distance = Growbed_Sensor1_Measurement() 
GPIO.output(RELAY_1, True) 
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: or 2 min worth of pumping? i dont understand this, can you explain with a less technical "water sensor" language xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop while **distance is greater than 4 and the elapsed time is less than 120 seconds.**

All you need to do is calculate the elapsed time, and incorporate the check into the `while` condition:

```
start_t = time.time()

while distance > 4 and (time.time() - start_t < 120):
   ...
```

This assumes however that the loop will loop constantly and wont get blocked somewhere. If you have potentially long-blocking calls within the loop, this won't work.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying your solution

@Carcigenicate
start_t = time()
while distance > 4 and (time() - start_t < 120):

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @franky29 Did you import the `time` module first?

Comment: yes. the time module is imported at the beginning of the my code or else I believe I wouldn't be able to use time.sleep(1) right?

Comment: @franky29 Right. Then use `time.time()`.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: that worked. Is it because I'm coding in Python 3 that I had to do time.time() instead of just time()?

Comment: @franky29 Honestly, it's been like 2 years since I've written Python. I can't remember exactly how it's imports work, or what the differences are for imports between 2 and 3. I'm using a 2 interpreter on my phone and time.time() works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop after 2 minutes.

```
def Pumping_to_Growbed():
    print ('')
    print ('Pumping water to growbed')
    time.sleep(1)
    distance = Growbed_Sensor1_Measurement()
    start = time()
    print ('Distance ', distance ,'cm')
    while distance > 4:
        GPIO.output(RELAY_1, False)
        print ('distance ', distance ,'cm')
        distance = Growbed_Sensor1_Measurement() 
        if time()-start >= 120:
            break
    GPIO.output(RELAY_1, True) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

this should work where time() is in the same package than sleep.

Comment: This looks reasonable. I'll try it tonight and will verify if it works.